# Why won't this PHP Email Script send to my Yahoo email?

Tags: php, email, smtp, yahoo-mail

so I have this script and I've been trying to figure out why it won't send to my Yahoo email account.

```
<?php


require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

require 'autoload.php';
//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);



$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
$mail->Host       = "tampabaydowns@tbdseats.com"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
                    
          
$mail->Username   = "tampabaydowns@tbdseats.com"; 
$mail->Password   = "~~~";  

$mail->SMTPSecure = "SSL";  
$mail->Port       = 465;   

$mail->From = "tampabaydowns@tbdseats.com";
$mail->FromName = "Tampa Bay Downs";

$mail->addAddress("~~@yahoo.com", "Austin");

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = 'This is a plain text';

try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

When I load the script page it says sent successfully but on the server, the email bounces back with this

```
 ~~@yahoo.com
    host mta6.am0.yahoodns.net [67.195.~~]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined MAIL FROM:<~~~@server.tbdseats.com> SIZE=1759:
    553 5.7.2 [TSS09] All messages from 217.~~ will be permanently deferred; Retrying will NOT succeed. See https://postmaster.verizonmedia.com/error-codes
```

I am unsure why this isn't working. When I replace my yahoo email with my gmail, it sends and my gmail gets the email from the server. Is there something different that has to be done with Yahoo?

My Yahoo email isn't blocking any incoming email addresses and it isn't in my spam.

I added ~~~ to the secure information, that is why that is there.

Can someone please help, I've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hours :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address of your provider's email server is blocked by yahoo. Use another server or service to relay your messages. As you pointed out gmail is relaying your messages correctly.

You can also ask your email admin to try fix it for you, but Yahoo is difficult to deal with on this kind of errors.

Comment: has yahoo always been like this?

Comment: After a phishing attack I had a server that fell into a yahoo's blacklist . In the end it was easier to route the traffic directed to yahoo through another IP. Their delisting process is obscure when compared for example with Microsoft's and google's.

Comment: Would it be easier to use a 3rd party email service to send emails out then rather than the servers email service?

Comment: If you don't manage that email server and it's not possible for you to be sure that the server is not sending something that can be considered as SPAM, I would recommend to use a third party server.